# What are some 'general solutions' for infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example we have the general solution for the infinite series for computing natural logs:

$$\ln(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x-1)^n$$

Where we can input any whole integer value for x and the series will give us exactly what the ln of that number is equal to, but aside from this I have been unable to find anything else. I am not strictly speaking of natural logs but general solutions of any type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that series does not give you the value of $\ln (x)$ for any whole integer value of $x$.

Comment: I really have no idea what you're asking. Do you want more examples of functions which can be calculated using infinite series?

Comment: your formula is incorrect, but also your question is not clear enough

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for [examples of Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series):

$$
\begin{align*}
e^x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
\sin x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-1\right)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}& x\in\left[-\pi,\pi\right]\\
\cos x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-1\right)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!}& x\in\left[-\pi,\pi\right]
\end{align*}
$$

You can construct a series representation for any function by taking its Taylor series. (However, some functions may not yield interesting expansions: for example, the Taylor series of any polynomial function will terminate and reduce to the function itself.)

A handy tool is WolframAlpha. For example, the query "series expansion ln(x)" yields [this page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+ln%28x%29), which gives a number of expansions, including the one in your question.

Comment: Hah, I totally forgot about those. Sometimes there is such a thing as being too focused on a task  :)

Answer (score 0):

[Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of any function will do, like the one you displayed.

That Wiki article lists a ton of examples.

Comment: Sure does, thanks for the link!